# Are there user/role libraries for Java on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authorization, roles

For Java web app development on GAE, I would like to add users androles management. Is there a basic Java library which provides role management (maybe based on annotations) which I could use as a foundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/features.html) supports various models, including role-based auth. You can use XML configuration, as well as annotation-based declaration or even implement your own providers.

Comment: looks great - this could be my first contact with Spring, finally :)

Comment: i don't know if the issues addressed here are still relevant, but it appears as though spring security may need some tweaking before it will work on app engine.  http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/964e7f5e42840d9c

Comment: Peter, it may be already resolved in version 3. I am not experiencing anything like that using that version in my GAE application.

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising:

> SecurityFilter is a Java Servlet
>   Filter that mimics container managed
>   security. It looks just like container
>   managed security to your app, as you
>   can call request.getRemoteUser(),
>   request.isUserInRole(), and
>   request.getUserPrincipal() and get
>   valid responses. The Security Filter
>   configuration file follows the web.xml
>   standard, which makes it easy to
>   switch to Security Filter from
>   container managed security, or switch
>   back as your requirements or
>   deployment environment details change.

http://securityfilter.sourceforge.net/